# find a solution for Trigonometric Functions

Tags: trigonometry

How to find a solution for 
$\sin(\theta)-\sqrt{\sin( \theta )+\cos( \theta )} -\cos^2(\theta) = 0 $
where $\theta $  in $[ 0 , 2\pi ] $

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{\sin t + \cos t} = \sin t - \cos^2t \tag 1$$ suppose $x = \cos t, y = \sin t.$  with this we have $$x^2 + y^2 = 1, x + y \ge 0, x+y = (y-x^2)^2 = y^2 -2yx^2 + x^4 $$ leads to $$y(1+2x^2)=1-x-x^2+x^4 = (1-x)-x^2(1-x^2) = (1-x)(1-x^2 - x^3) $$  therefore $$y = \frac{(1-x)(1-x^2 - x^3)}{1+2x^2} =\sqrt{1-x^2} \tag 2$$  the solutions are $$x = -0.6390,\,-0.543689,\, 0, 1. $$
the corresponding $t$ values are $$ 2.3364, 2.1455, 1.5707$$

$\bf edit:$ i needed to check the solutions again with the original equation because i squared it. $x = 1$ needs to be discarded. $x = 0, t = \pi/2$ is good. i checked $x = -0.5436,\, t = 2.1455$ is good.

Comment: $t=0$ gives $1=-1$ in the original equation, so it's not a solution. $t=1.5707$ (presumably, $t=\pi/2$) is even worse, as the left side becomes $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: $   I think t= \pi /2 is a solution , can you explain why it is even worse.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, what do you mean $t = \pi/2, x = 0$ is not a solution?

Comment: Sorry, $t=\pi/2$ is fine.